# Access prototype from generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible for a class with a generic such as `class Foo<A> {}` to access `A`'s prototype or use a typeguard on `A`, or run any sort of logic based on `A`'s type alone - without having been provided the class, interface, or instance to `Foo`'s constructor (i.e. `Foo` has no constructor or the constructor does not accept an argument of type `A`)?

There are several answers about accessing the constructor, such as [Generic Type Inference with Class Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677592/generic-type-inference-with-class-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I am only interested in running different logic based on the type, not instantiating a new instance of it.

Specifically, I want to know if `A.prototype` has a certain method defined on it.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only allow `A` classes with a specific function you can use the extends mechanism with generic as well, like this:

```
interface B {
   myMandatoryFunction()
}

class Foo<A extends B> {
   //...
}
```

If an action in your Generic class is based on on `A` having a function or not on its prototype, you will have to instantiate a A object and look at it's prototype because Typescript typing is just involved at compilation and checking type of object during code execution is done exactly like in js with `instanceof` method and thus is not applicable to types

Comment: "will have to instantiate A object" - so the _only_ way is if an instance of A is passed to Foo as an argument?