# Infer parameter type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to construct a function which takes a class(`Clazz`) as an argument and returns an instance of the same class as follows

```
function myFunction(Clazz) {
    ...
    return new Clazz();
}
```

Is there any way to infer the type of `Clazz` and set it as the return type of this function?
I am aware that I can probably acheive this using generics as follows:

```
function myFunction<T>(Clazz: new () => T): T {
    ...
    return new Clazz();
}

var instance = myFunction<myClass>(myClass)
```

But my intention is to get rid of that repitition of `myClass` as seen in the above usage

Comment: [As shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696435/6397798) you can avoiding the repetition by adding a type to the variable and let the compiler infer the type parameter for you, like this: `var instance: myClass = myFunction(myClass)`

Comment: @bracco23 that wouldn't be getting rid of the repition. I still have to type `myClass` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just remove the `<myClass>` and you are good to go:

```
function myFunction<T>(Clazz: new () => T): T {
    return new Clazz();
}

class myClass {
    public m() { }
}
var instance = myFunction(myClass) // instance is typed as myClass, T is infered to myClass
instance.m() // ok
```

Typescript will infer type parameters based on arguments to a function. It is rare you have to pass explicit type parameters (and is generally a sign of bad use of type parameters, not always, but generally).