# Generic repository that creates instances of generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a generic repository in TypeScript that serializes/deserializes using localStorage.

I've read many [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class) questions [regarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677592/generic-type-inference-with-class-argument) `new()` in ts, but they are full of foos, bars and bazes, and I can't find a real example. Most importantly, I can't find an example that can create a new instance inside a generic class (all examples I found assume the type is known, whereas as you'll see below the type is unknown in the repository class).

A "Dog" entity:

```
interface IEntity { }

class Dog implements IEntity {

  constructor(json: string);     // called when deserializing
  constructor(name: string, age: number);
  constructor(jsonOrName: string, age?: number) { /* implementation... */ }

  name: string;
  age: number;

  toJSON() {    // called when serializing (via JSON.stringify)
    //...
  }
}
```

And a repository to serialize/deserialize to/from localStorage.

```
class Repository<T extends IEntity> {

  constructor(private key: string) { }

  read(): T | null {
    const s = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    if (!s) return null;
    const value = JSON.parse(s);
    return new T(value);            // <----------- how do I do this?
  }

  write(value: T): void {
    localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

}
```

The intended use is:

```
const dogRepository = new Repository<Dog>("dog");
const dog = dogRepository.read();
if (dog) console.log(dog.name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type system is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at runtime, so the type named `T` will not exist as anything you can construct via the `new` operator.  Instead you need your `Respository<T>` instances to hold an actual runtime constructor for your `T`.  For example:

```
class Repository<T extends IEntity> {

  // take a key *and* a constructor which operates on a json string
  constructor(private key: string, private ctor: new (json: string) => T) {}

  read(): T | null {
    const s = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    if (!s) return null;
    return new this.ctor(s); // use the ctor on the JSON (don't parse, right?)
  }

  write(value: T): void {
    localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```

And then you'd have to change this as well:

```
const dogRepository = new Repository("dog", Dog); // pass ctor here, T is inferred
const dog = dogRepository.read();
if (dog) console.log(dog.name);
```

Does that make sense?  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFFzDAT2QbwF8AoYhAGzgGcrkARAewHNlgBbAB3IjYnFoxZcBYsmQIGIKmCgBXBGAZQAFACsqkgFzJpUUEwCUAbmQB6U+LjluAE2QB3ABZ9kNiFWjArwAF77R4pK68ooqIHC82rr6ADTIcEwQ2iCybABG0MYBElIyIUpqGiAA8lAAchFJOjKx8YkA-MmpGVAGImJipgBUrJzcvOBwYMCSAHTjyF2mASQB4bwAhFE1IExGAQkQS8gp6dDrAYoAUgDKxWXKbfgzxLMU1LQAShAcDFTYSjgAPAAqyBAAD0gIBsAkww1wAD52oFcnIFAUOHoAG5DFAAawgOGWelWcSRwFRkHEoWSEHsyEKWmquMMyAAvNCfldZmIoBA4DZLto-gAfHayawwsQ5aQ6BnIcgMBBWE6hTajRJgVCQNjKMCOYBUUaYnBZDqsGCUhZUNrssCyKAgAXWdYG82W60gcnIDVa0YIlSmu3IVkOPSQZSo8iyKrM7TIhjAOzXA1SmXkOVKBUeZWq9Wa7W6uKnc6jaKrYAwHBBqyhgz6323UiisCuZjPV7vUJ4ek7F2Nt4fKAlgBENmYvbijEM61r9ZYbYHTE7zc+o3ZnMu6yLlOnbVFDG4oylTGU09G8wgWSAA)