# Working with classes and generics in TypeScript - use of new()?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[From the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics):

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary to refer to class types by their constructor functions. For example:
>
> ```
> function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
>    return new c();
> }
> ```

To be honest: This syntax has me completely confused. If I'd be reading the `create` function the way I'm used to, I'd think `create` is a function that takes an argument `c` in the shape of an object with a key of `new()` (why the parenthesis?) of type T. Instead this function takes a class as an argument.
I also don't understand what this has to do with the constructor function of the class since `new()` by itself has no relation to the constructor function of the class.

Second example from the docs:

```
class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: string;
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
```

This also takes in a class but uses a different syntax for the argument. Again, I'm really confused with the use of `new()` (creates empty objects points `this` to it) here.

Comment: It's confusing mostly because the docs use two different notations that are equivalent. `{new(): T; }` uses [this style of declaring functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) while `new () => A` [uses this style](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type). In both cases it's the same thing though - it denotes that it takes a constructor function that produces `A` types.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696435/9695286

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for your answer! Thanks for the two function format links. But wouldn't your answer imply that the argument `c` would need to be an object with a method called `new`? To my knowledge classes don't have a method called `new`. In the second example `c: new() => A` would even imply that the argument is a function (not a class) called `new`- or am I completly wrong here?

Comment: @Xen_mar no, since it's `new () : A` as opposed to `{ new: () => A }`. The latter would mean an object with a `new` property which contains a function. The trouble comes from the first link I posted - you can define a function signature as `interface Add { (a: number, b: number): number }` which looks a lot like an object but it actually only defines a function. I think the overloaded `interface` style declaration is very misleading. Then there is the further problem that you can also define the same function as `type Add = (a: number, b: number) => number`

Comment: @VLAZ I'm just a little confused since `new (): A`  also seem to compile into the type declaration for an object with the property `new`: https://codepen.io/florianmartens/pen/oNbpXeM

Comment: @Xen_mar it doesn't [produce that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQB2YAtggFzQQAuSx5A5tALzQBEAYkgQATHgG50AX3TpWjZADMwwBHERIAwgHtyTJHmCNNSDNgoIA7gAoAlPXjJxU9PLzkDxbdGCCwc+0gBGS2B6VDMrW1UHaAlI-zRMLEFGPCRycK8bR2kAehyIahVIaEYACyKCTQA3FQI8Rmg8RBgwCkKhaFkFJQRnV3dPbwRfBH8AJmC7NS0dZn1DJDi1BNNk1PTyC0zrbPRgbSYKTUYZ3XmjLhXsTfN6FzdGD3SbNGg1tIz-F6knIZH-IL+HZ7Hx+NQTIHiEHDMHIILkY6nOYGIzAv6wpATBEnA7IhbAoA). Again `{new () : A}` means a *function* and because it has a `new` there it's a constructor. An object with `new` property is `{new: () => A}` note the colon.

Comment: To be honest, I'm still struggling with the concept. I get that `{(): A}`is a function. And adding the `new` turns it into something that TypeScript links to the constructor function of the passed class. It's just super awkward because obviously calling `() => ExampleClass` has little to no relation to the constructor class in normal JS. But I think this question defeated me. Thanks for all your input so far. You did a great job explaining this.

Comment: "*And adding the new turns it into something that TypeScript links to the constructor function of the passed class*" it's actually a lot simpler than that `{(): A}` is a function that *when called* produces an instance of `A`. While `{ new () : A`}` is a function that when called *with `new`* will produce an instance of `A`. That's pretty much it - `new` in the signature means you are allowed to call it with the `new` keyword. So the difference is between invoking `c()` and `new c()`.