# Get constructor/instance from generic type in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I am trying to create instance from generic type `T` for example,

```
class Factory {
    public static generate<T>(): T { 
      return new T();
  }
}
```

But since `T` is just a *type* not **constructor**, we can't do that.

Is it impossible to create an instance from a generic type in TypeScript?

I'v also read these articles but could not found a solution.

- [TypeScript #2037](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2037)
- [How to create a new object from type parameter in generic class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/how-to-create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class-in-typescript)
- [How can I create a new instance of the generic type of my Typescript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436747/how-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-the-generic-type-of-my-typescript-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new object from type parameter in generic class in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/how-to-create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The type information used in TypeScript is erased before runtime, so the information about `T` is not available when you make the call to `new T()`.

That's why all of the alternate solutions depend upon the constructor being passed, such as with [this example of creating a class dynamically](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/12/dynamically-creating-typescript-classes-based-on-type-argument/):

```
interface ParameterlessConstructor<T> {
    new (): T;
}

class ExampleOne {
    hi() {
        alert('Hi');
    }
}

class Creator<T> {
    constructor(private ctor: ParameterlessConstructor<T>) {

    }
    getNew() {
        return new this.ctor();
    }
}

var creator = new Creator(ExampleOne);

var example = creator.getNew();
example.hi();
```