# Generics: Type as property name

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible with generics to pass an object for usage as not only the type, but as the key?

```
interface store {
  category: string
}

interface ajaxResponse<T> {
  data: ajaxData<T>
  errors: string[]
  success: boolean
}

interface ajaxData<T> {
  rewards: {
    amount: number
    error: string
  }
  T: T
}

function get<T>(url): Promise<ajaxResponse<T>> {
    // make ajax GET request
    // return json object
}

let res = await get<store>('/my/url')

res.data.store.category
```

When I do that, it says

> Property 'store' does not exist on type 'ajaxData'

Is there a way for me to access that property? It works once compiled since all that is removed, but how can I get it working in the editor?

**Edit**

After thinking about it, I think I don't want the interface and the property to be the same. I think I would want to use an `interface` with name `x`, so maybe something like this:

```
let res1 = await get<storeA, 'category'>('/my/url1')
let res2 = await get<storeB, 'catList'>('/my/url2')

res1.data.category.category
res2.data.catList.categories
```

Comment: It "works" because `T: T` declares a property named `T` - there is no generic parameter substitution happening for property names

Comment: What do you mean there is no parameter substitution happening? Do you mean I am not doing one, or one doesn't exist?

Comment: I see `res.data.store.category` in your code, and I suppose that you expect `ajaxData<T> ... { T: T}` to expand into `{store: store}` when you pass `store` as `T`. What's actually happening is it's expanded into `{T: store}`.

Comment: Yeah I can call `res.data.T.category` in the editor, but that breaks in the javascript at runtime. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then you should have some code somewhere that will initialize `T` in   the ajaxData with some value that conforms to the `store` interface when you call `get<store>`, and for that you probably need to pass a constructor or something as normal argument to `get` along with generic type argument `<store>`. [Interfaces and generics only describe shape of objects for the compiler to do typechecking, they have no effect at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542489/get-constructor-instance-from-generic-type-in-typescript).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes if you have property name as explicit literal type, you can declare a type having property with that name by using [mapped type syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type A<T, PropertyName extends string> = {[P in PropertyName]: T}
```

So the complete example should look like

```
interface store {
  category: string
}

interface ajaxResponse<T, PropertyName extends string> {
  data: ajaxData<T, PropertyName>
  errors: string[]
  success: boolean
}

type ajaxData<T, PropertyName extends string> = {
  rewards: {
    amount: number
    error: string
  }
} & {[P in PropertyName]: T}




function get<T, PropertyName extends string>(url): Promise<ajaxResponse<T, PropertyName>> {
    // make ajax GET request
    // return json object
  return null;
}

async function test() {
  let res = await get<store, 'store'>('/my/url')

  res.data.store.category
}
```

Comment: do you have any docs on `& {[P in PropertyName]: T }`? I have never seen that before. I have also never used `type ... = {}` either.

Comment: It's called [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), I added a link. It has to be a `type`, not interface, so if you need to have additional properties in it you can do that only using `&` as [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)