# TypeScript Generics: Function that returns constructor of instance specified as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm learning TypeScript. I've been getting my head around generics, and I've encountered a slight issue that I'm struggling to find answers for.

I have Googled lots and lots of search queries, but because of the ambiguity of the search terms, and lack of knowledge of technical names for certain language constructs, I'm getting lots of noise.

I read three relevant pages of documentation on TypeScript's website, and could not find the information I need. Perhaps I overlooked something, and if that is the case, a link to a good explanation would be appreciated.

I want to write a function that returns the constructor of an instance specified as a parameter that retains typing, since this.constructor in TypeScript is not of the type of the class.

To be very clear, I know I can do this:

```js
const aa2 = (a.constructor as typeof A).make();
```

This is a stripped down case:

```js
class A {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;

    constructor(prop1: string, prop2: number) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    method() {

    }

    static make() {
        return new this('test', 42);
    }
}

function constructor<T>(instance: T): { new(...args): T } {
    return instance.constructor as { new(...args): T };
}

const a = A.make();

// Property 'make' does not exist on type 'new(...args: any[]) => A'
const aa = constructor(a).make();


// This works, but is not pretty
const aa2 = (a.constructor as typeof A).make();
```

It needs to work on any class, with constructor parameters or without.

I can do the inverse:

```js
export function make<T>(type: { new(...args): T }, ...args): T {
    return new type(...args);
}

make(A, 'test', 42).method();
```

It seems there is some critical element to this I'm not getting. If you can spot precisely where I'm going wrong in my thinking, I welcome a good explanation of my misunderstanding.

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve the constructor?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - The why doesn't matter. I have a question, and I'm looking for an answer. I know you are probably pondering my use-case is, and whether my use case is in itself a misconception, so that you may remedy that. I find it a little annoying when I find questions that are answered with, "why are you doing that". My reasons may or may not be valid, but it matters not, it's still a valid question. Even if the solution is not appropriate to my use case, it may be for somebody else who finds an answer to this question.

Comment: I asked that question to understand your problem even further. There is thing called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and sometimes we, people trying to answer questions here, may not understand true intention of OP. I've encountered couple of problems that solution was simpler than what OP tried to do. So, my question is as much valid as yours. So, "why" indeed matters a lot

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - in that case, my assumption was incorrect. I have seen many examples of what I described, it did look like another such example.

I have several. For example a base class returning a new instance of this. I want it to work for all derived classes without explicitly overriding the method on derived classes to return an instance of the derived class explicitly. Imagine a Model class with a `clone` method, you'd expect that method to return a new instance of `this.constructor`, passing in the same data that was passed to the original instance constructor.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - I have lots of similar such use cases. I'm porting an app from JS to TS.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - I wanted to encapsulate the translation of types in a function to prettify it. I like a balance between explicit readability and prettiness.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - apologies if my initial comment came across a bit dismissive. I tend to avoid asking questions on StackOverflow because of the culture that is often tough on newcomers who don't know the law of the land here. I get irritated more and more when I happen across instances of it. And there are many, hence my assumption. Obviously I'm mistaken in this case.

Comment: all is well :) I can tell why these kinds of questions can irritate people and I agree there are some condescending people here. Back to the topic, would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542489/get-constructor-instance-from-generic-type-in-typescript) help your case?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner - it does, I'll look into it further and evaluate how that can apply to my case. Thank you for your time.

Comment: you are welcome, hope you can come up with a fully working solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to move from an instance type to the class type. This would only be possible if `constructor` was typed as the class type (which it is not) There is an open ticket to make [this happen](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) but it has been open and in discussion for a long time.

If you control the client classes you can add a member to the class to make the method work correctly:

```
class TraceableClass<TThis> {
  private typedConstructor!: TThis
}
class A<TThisClas = typeof A> extends TraceableClass<TThisClas>{
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;

    constructor(prop1: string, prop2: number) {
        super();
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    method() {

    }

    static make() {
        return new this('test', 42);
    }
}

function constructor<T>(instance: TraceableClass<T>): T {
    return instance.constructor as  any as T;
}

const a = A.make();

// Ok now
const aa = constructor(a).make();
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOZgFMwCMTIMLigHllgAsBLCAPmgG8AoaaAB3hIDcwAXZadgTweQAmWAPYA7CO3gBXYO2HwAhAC44xMjQC+NUJBgBBAmog5I0ALzc+yYQDNoeysgAenUQJgIkqDNlwRDpMa45LT09EzCDACMKhLMogDmANx0YREMAEwqolIAtmjI8Cmp9MBicTJy8AAU6THQcSSJADSM8JFZ0Dn5hQCU1CVh9BBS-DW9KUND7IEAdHXmbZFRk1P0M2Tz7ZmL6Rmr9FqDucgzwgLV-bSDR0MSHCTA0LlgANbIlwNr9PCnUvCiLrIADu3EC1QA5JwJBDWgAWDITG6aGg0GxSUSyEhiaBlcSSSryAjkapNe6Y5AqTwodCYEz4WDkXpUr5hX7sf6AsnsMAU2Z4iqyeTQUwi0Q8EUeFJHAXsEWLPSzF7vS7FWUisCLWXSIU1MC9JVvD5IoA)

Comment: I see, I'm both pleased that there is a way, but disappointed because it feels convoluted. I guess for now I'll keep casting `this.constrcutor`. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: @thephpdev you are welcomed, sorry I don't have better news. At least now you know :)