# How specify class definition as parameter type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to pass type information for class, with hinting the compiler that the given parameter is not an instance of a class but the class definition. How can I do that?

```
import * as Routes from '../routes';
import * as Entities from '../entities';

export class RouteManager {
  public router = Router();
  private connection = getConnectionManager().get();

  constructor() {
    this.addRoute(Routes.VideoRoute, Entities.Video);
  }

  addRoute(routeClass: AbstractRoute<AbstractEntity>, entity: AbstractEntity): void {
    const instance = new routeClass(entity, this.connection.getRepository(entity))
    this.router.get(instance.route, instance.find);
  }
}
```

Here the compiler complains about the `new routeClass(entity, this.connection.getRepository(entity))` line because it thinks `routeClass` is an instance of `AbstractRoute<AbstractEntity>` and not the exported class definition for it.

I have tried using`AbstractRoute<AbstractEntity>.constructor` but Typescript doesn't seem to know this structure.

Comment: You linked to this question o.O

Comment: sorry! :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698710/defining-typescript-generic-type-with-new

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax for this looks a little bit weird. Basically you define a signature that uses something like `new(...args: any[]) => T`. You of course can be more strict by replacing `T` with your class and the `args` with the `constructor` signature.

I would recommend something like this:

```
class Foo {}
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function createFoo(thing: Constructor<Foo>) { return new thing(); }
```

Comment: It throws the following: Type 'typeof Video' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<Video>'.
  Type 'Video' is not assignable to type 'Video'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

Comment: There is no `Video` type in your example, but from the looks of it you're using the same identifier multiple times. That's also what the error tells you: *Two different types with this name exist* PS: This seems to be an issue with your code. Can you copy/paste my example code into your code base + check if it works?

Comment: okay hear me out: what if I want to say that I can accept any class so long as it extends class `Bar`?

Comment: You mean polymorphism?