# Typescript: A type that allows only objects which implement the same interface

Tags: typescript, interface

How can I force environment.service to only accept values which implement ServiceInterface?

```
interface ServiceInterface {
  id: string
}

class ServiceA implements ServiceInterface {
  id = 'a'
}

class ServiceB implements ServiceInterface {
  id = 'b'
}

interface Environment {
  service: ServiceInterface
}

const environment: Environment = {
  service: ServiceA // TS2741: Property 'id' is missing in type 'typeof ServiceA'...
}
```

I want people to be able to switch out the service in the environment for their own implementation of the service, but only as long as their new implementation adheres to ServiceInterface.

The reason I cannot use an instance `service: new ServiceA()` is because I am using Angular, where the dependency injection takes care of instantiating the class. I have to supply the class to the dependency injection system. To do that I import my environment file, where I need to make sure that the class added there implements the interface.

Comment: ```const environment: Environment = {
    service: { id: 'a' }
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solutions thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606912/how-specify-class-definition-as-parameter-type-in-typescript/43607255#43607255)

```
interface ServiceInterface {
  id: string
}

type Implements<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class ServiceA implements ServiceInterface {
  id = 'a'
}

class ServiceB implements ServiceInterface {
  id = 'b'
}

interface Environment {
  service: Implements<ServiceInterface>
}

const environment: Environment = {
  service: ServiceB
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```js
const environment: Environment = {
  service: ServiceA
}
```

the value of the `service` key is not an *instance* of the `ServiceA` class, but the class itself.

You need to pass an actual instance of the class to satisfy the constraint:

```js
const environment: Environment = {
  service: new ServiceA()
}
```

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Is there a way around this though?

Maybe a custom type to achieve what I want instead?

Comment: Custom type is only compile time. You need to have value. When you do new X you get instance value.