# Pass class definition as parameter & reference static member in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, parameters, static, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a class definition as a parameter to a function and then access a static member of the class inside the function, but Typescript says the static property doesn't exist on the type and asks if I want to access the static member instead.  I do, but can't figure out how to specify the type of the parameter in such a way that this is allowed.  It feels like this should be simple and I'm just missing some small detail, but what is it?

Code example, referencing [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3):

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';

//With a first param typed Web3 regardless of name, Typescript throws an error:
//Property 'providers' does not exist on type 'Web3'.
//Did you mean to access the static member 'Web3.providers' instead?ts(2576)
const getWebSocketProvider = function(
        Web3ClassDefinition: Web3, 
        host: string, 
        port: string
    ) {
    //Custom options and other components motivating use of a wrapper function
    //are removed for this minimal example.
    //Adding .constructor just before .providers changes the error to
    //"Property 'providers' does not exist on type 'Function'.ts(2339)"
    //Adding .prototype.constructor just before .providers changes the error to
    //"Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'Web3'.ts(2339)"
    return new Web3ClassDefinition.prototype.constructor.providers.WebsocketProvider(
        'wss://'+host+':'+port
    );
};

//This call also has an error:
//Argument of type 'typeof Web3' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Web3'.
//Type 'typeof Web3' is missing the following properties from type 'Web3':
//defaultAccount, defaultBlock, currentProvider, setProvider, and 5 more.ts(2345)
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607255/798371 solves that, 
//but then the main error changes to
//"Property 'providers' does not exist on type Constructor<Web3>."
getWebSocketProvider(Web3, '123.45.67.89', '1234');
```

Note that the type definition in the GPL-licensed library (index.d.ts) includes the static `providers` member:

```js
export default class Web3 {
    constructor();
    constructor(provider: provider);
    constructor(provider: provider, net: net.Socket);
    //...
    static readonly providers: Providers;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the type `Web3` denotes an instance of the `Web3` class rather than the class itself. To pass the class itself as a parameter, you will need to use the type `typeof Web3`. This is also what the somewhat cryptic type error tries to convey: Argument of type 'typeof Web3' (i.e. actual parameter `Web3`) is not assignable to parameter of type 'Web3' (i.e. formal parameter `Web3ClassDefinition`).

If you change the type of `Web3ClassDefinition` to `typeof Web3`, and drop the `.prototype.constructor` part, the code type checks:

```
const getWebSocketProvider = function(
        Web3ClassDefinition: typeof Web3, 
        host: string, 
        port: string
    ) {
    return new Web3ClassDefinition.providers.WebsocketProvider(
        'wss://'+host+':'+port
    );
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAdQKYCMDMcBmUIjgcgHdU18BuAWAChqBjCAOwGd4BzJGZFAZQloGsOABRwA3YABMkUOAF4sAVwa0YwRgApqcbTu1c0AYQA2AQyZMAIkkzAGwVYwBccGAE8wSCJkQkANHC1dHQALCBZnFihbVn9AoLhIWAiYKIZWOLgASjgAbwyoDgUoBjgGJEIfdGMzS2tbezUGADowMUlpJiauJj5BGBEIcSkoTSp47SJzRwB6afwAalCWefxHBcSYDMzKKgBfHep2TlReAWE24fV9f3wARgAmNCaAFgBWJoA2AHYmgA4ATnwNweaGe%20G21CAA)

Comment: While this compiles, it unfortunately throws a runtime error that `Web3ClassDefinition` doesn't have the `providers` object. `Web3ClassDefinition` is of type `object` with contents `[Module: null prototype] { default: [Function: Web3] { /* all the content is in here. */ }}`. Adding `.Web3` or `.default` before `.providers` produces an error like `Property 'Web3' does not exist on type 'typeof Web3'.ts(2339)`.

Comment: That shouldn't be related to passing `Web3` as a parameter, i.e. directly calling `Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(..)` will probably also fail in your code. If I paste the code from the playground in an empty project it works ok (hangs on the constructor call). Maybe there's something wrong with your import, or project setup? You could try it on an empty project yourself and see where the differences are.