# Typescript Generic Repository - instantiate the generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, repository, abstract-class

I am trying to build a generic Repository in Typescript (using DynamoDB, but that's not relevant).

I have a base repository class which receives a generic type. On this class, I have a `getById` method, which is supposed to return the entity object as an instance of the generic class:

```js
export abstract class BaseRepository<T> implements WriteInterface<T>, ReadInterface<T> {
  getById(id: string): Promise<T> {
    const findParams = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: { id }
    }
    return this.documentClient.get(findParams).promise().then((data) => {
      // this next line is my problem
      // Ideally, I would just instantiate with the new() keyword.
      let inst: T = new T(data.Item);
      return inst;
    });
  }
}
```

The error I get for the above is

```
error TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

    96       let inst: T = new T(data.Item);
```

There are some similar questions, and the most found answer is using a factory function. The problem with that approach is you still need a concrete type for passing to the factory, but I'm trying to use the factory with the generic type.

For example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698710/how-to-constraint-a-generic-type-to-have-new) I've tried doing

```js
create<T>(type: {new(): T}): T {
    let newEntity: T = new type();
    return newEntity;
  }
  getById(id: string): Promise<T> {
    const findParams = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: { id }
    }
    return this.documentClient.get(findParams).promise().then((data) => {
      let inst: T = this.create(T);
      return inst;
    });
  }
```

The above renders the same exact error as before.

I'm pretty sure it's possible to achieve what I'm trying, because I think [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) does something very similar, but I couldn't find / understand how it works there.

**Later edit**

So, thanks to Nadia's answer, the solution seems to still be a factory function, but what I was missing was passing the type through the constructor. So the correct implementation should be:

```
export abstract class BaseRepository<T> implements WriteInterface<T>, ReadInterface<T> {
  protected tableName: string;
  protected documentClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;
  private create: {new (): T;};

  constructor(tableName: string, create: { new (): T; }) {
    this.create = create;
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  }

  getById(id: string): Promise<T> {
    const findParams = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: { id }
    }
    return this.documentClient.get(findParams).promise().then((data) => {
      let inst: T = new this.create();
      return inst;
    });
  }
}
```

And then, when I want to extend this base repository, the way to do it is:

```
import { BaseRepository } from './base.repository';

const tableName = process.env.DDB_TOKENS_TABLE;

export class TokenRepository extends BaseRepository<TokenEntity> {
  constructor() {
    super(tableName, TokenEntity);
  }
}
```

Not sure if there is a wat to not create a specific constructor where you just pass the entity to the `super()`.

Comment: What will `T` be? are you sure you want to instantiate it? If it is the type of the object  returned from `documentClient.get` then you can just cast to it using `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS does need a concrete type so it knows which constructor to call. Fortunately there is a way to provide - via the constructor of your generic class. It'll look something like this:

```
class BaseRepository<T>  {
private create: { new (): T; };
constructor(create: { new (): T; }) {
      this.create = create;
  }
getById(id: string): T {
    ...
    let inst: T = new this.create();
    ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nadia. Seems like your example works perfectly. I'll update the question with the answer, and the example of how to extend it in specific repositories.
Thanks again, great answer!

Comment: A question, is there any way of not creating the specific constructor, which passes the entity to the ```super()```?

Comment: Why do you need a specific constructor? if you declare a concrete class, say `MyRepository extends BaseRepository<MyClass>` you don't need to specify the constructor, you can go on calling it (`new MyRepository(MyClass)`)