# Typescript: error creating an instance of a generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following TypeScript fragment:

```
class TBase { }

class Foo<T extends TBase>
{
    f() :T {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

The `new()` line throws the following compilation error:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

What am I missing please?

Comment: TypeScript's generics are based on type-erasure rather than being reified, consequently you can't do `new T()` (after-all, `tsc` has no way of knowing if `T` even has a parameterless constructor or not). If you want `class Foo` to be a generic factory type then it will need a factory-function `() => T` passed in to its own constructor, saved in a field, and then invoked inside `f()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `T` is a type parameter and not a concrete type which cannot be used to create a new instance of an object. Whenever you use new keyword, you are trying to create a new instance of `T`, which is not allowed because `T` is a type, not a value.

Instead, define a concrete type extending from `TBase` for `T` when you create an instance of `Foo` , then use that to create a new instance.

Comment: Any way to provide an equivalent of C#'s "new()" constraint, tell TypeScript that T is supposed to have a default constructor?

Comment: You can just change your above code.. 
`f(myT: new () => T): T {  return new myT();  }`
Have a look at this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698710/how-to-constraint-a-generic-type-to-have-new

Comment: That adds a parameter to f(), thus forcing a change at every point of call of f(). Given the larger project, there can be a cheaper alternative. Point taken though.