# what is new() in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I encountered `new()` in the official document [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) about generics.

Here is the code context:

```
function create<T>(c: { new(): T; } ): T {
    return new c();
}
```

The above code is transpiled to the following JavaScript code:

```
function create(c) {
    return new c();
}
```

`new()` is illegal syntax in JavaScript. What does it mean in TypeScript?

Furthermore, what does `{new(): T; }` mean? I know it must be a type, but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Comment: used in an interface or inline interface it describes signature of the constructor.

Comment: @toskv new() looks like a function invocation. Why it is the signature of the constructor?

Comment: in es5 the way you implement classes is by creating in instances of functions. that's just the way to do it new functionName().

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`new()` describes a constructor signature in typescript. What that means is that it describes the shape of the constructor.
For instance take `{new(): T; }`. You are right it is a type. It is the type of a class whose constructor takes in no arguments. Consider the following examples

```
function create<T>(c: { new(): T; } ): T {
    return new c();
}
```

What this means is that the function `create` takes an argument whose constructor takes no arguments and returns an instance of type `T`.

```
function create<T>(c: { new(a: number): T; } ): T
```

What this would mean is that the create function takes an argument whose constructor accepts one number `a` and returns an instance of type T. 
Another way to explain it can be, the type of the following class

```
class Test {
    constructor(a: number){

    }
}
```

would be `{new(a: number): Test}`

Comment: maybe adding a class implementing them (and their transpilation to javascript) would help clear the problem.

Comment: After transpilation the `type` would have no existence since there is no concept of types in javascript and hence there would be no `new()`. There is no such thing as `new()` in javascript.. it is only in typescript

Comment: ofcourse there is new functionName() in javascript. you create a new instance of that function object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Yes but there is no `new()`, there is `new functionName()` and `new ClassName()` but no `new()`

Comment: ah, that is right indeed. :) it's just typescript stuff

Comment: I can't get the example to work function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
    return new c();
} and is copy paste.https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: It seems to work fine. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20create%3CT%3E(c%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%20%7D)%3A%20T%20%7B%20return%20new%20c()%3B%20%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(create%3CObject%3E(Object))). If possible could you reproduce your problem on the typescript playground and share it here?

Comment: Add something about `['new']():` and `new: () =>`.

Comment: Honestly, couldn't the folks at Typescript think of a more cryptic way of doing this?

Comment: So this would only work if the constructor of the class had no arguments? 

Can we generalize this for any class?

Answer (score 15):

The new keyword is used to create an instance of a class, so in its simplest form:

```
class SimpleClass {
}
```

Would be constructed as follows:

```
let simpleClassInstance = new SimpleClass();
```

This is all well and good, but how do you create an instance of a generic class, i.e.:

```
class SimpleClassFactory< T > {
    static create( T ) {
        return new T(); // compile error could not find symbol T
    }
}
```

Would be used as follows:

```
let simpleClassInstance = SimpleClassFactory.create(SimpleClass);
```

Here, we are attempting to use the class definition to create an instance of a class.  This will generate a compile error.

So we need to refer to the type by its constructor signature:

```
class SimpleClassFactory< T > {
    static create( type: { new(): T ;} ) {
        return new type(); // succeeds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### What is new() => T?

Essentially it is a way to declare an "Object Type" in which you can then create an instance of said "Object Type" with.

### Example

```ts
class MyClass {
  // ...
}

// Creates new object types that don't have arguments in their constructors
function createObjectGivenObjectType<T>(ObjectType: new() => T): T {
  return new ObjectType();
}

const myObject: MyClass = createObjectGivenObjectType(MyClass);
```

---

### Simplify new() => T

I personally find it confusing when I see new() => T in a codebase. To simplify the problem, and to allow for better code readability, abstract this idea away from other devs by declaring a new type in your codebase called `Type`:

```ts
export type Type<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

Then the above `createObjectGivenObjectType` function can become:

```ts
// Then this reads as: ObjectType is a type of T
function createObjectGivenObjectType<T>(ObjectType: Type<T>): T {
  return new ObjectType();
}
```

---

> Furthermore, what does { new(): T; } mean? I know it must be a type, but how?

From the example you give it appears to be a more obtuse way of passing in an "Object Type" to a function.

Some examples that all do the same thing:

```ts
function create<T>(c: { new(): T; }): T {
  return new c();
}
create(X);


function create<T>(c: new() => T): T {
  return new c();
}
create(X);

function create<T>(c: Type<T>): T {
  return new c();
}
create(X);
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the documentation is mentions that the syntax is for "When creating factories in TypeScript using generics".

If you look at a larger example that they have:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string;
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper;
}

function findKeeper<A extends Animal, K> (a: {new(): A;
    prototype: {keeper: K}}): K {

    return a.prototype.keeper;
}

findKeeper(Lion).nametag;  // typechecks!

a: {new(): A
// is actually creating a new instance of the type A which is extending Animal.
// it is necessary to refer to class types by their constructor functions
```

Comment: still not clear. Can you give a simpler, not complex, example of new()? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

{new(): T } actually is a class type that is referred to as a
constructor function. another syntax of representing a type as a constructor function is by using this syntax

```
new () => Type
```

In the case of the create functions, an alias could be represented as

```
function create<T>(c: new () => T ): T {
  return new c();
}
```

Constructor functions are generally helpful in typescript for creating class instances from factory functions.
In the case of the factory function 'create' above, it accepts a class type whose constructor has no arguments "{new(): T; }" and returns an instance of the class "T".

Example:

```
class BeeKeeper {
  hasMask: boolean = true;
}
     
const newClass = create(BeeKeeper)

console.log(newClass instanceof BeeKeeper) // Prints true
```

constructor functions can also be represented as below in the case of  a constructor function that accepts arguments

```
new (b: string) => T
       or
{new(b: string): T }
```