# How to go about understanding the type `new (...args: any[]) => any`

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, instanceof

I'm reading through the code of the [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) library and it has the following `isInstance` method in it:

```
/**
 * Checks if the value is an instance of the specified object.
 */
isInstance(object: any, targetTypeConstructor: new (...args: any[]) => any) {
    return targetTypeConstructor
        && typeof targetTypeConstructor === "function"
        && object instanceof targetTypeConstructor;
}
```

Any thoughts on how to go about understanding the type `new (...args: any[]) => any`?  This is the first time I'm seeing this type of construct ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's reduce the type to smaller, bite size pieces that are more easily understood and then build back up to the full thing.

First, let's drop the `new` from our mind and focus on the latter part of the definition:

> `(...args: any[]) => any`

Next let's forget about the arguments for now:

> `() => any`

Hopefully this is familiar as a function that returns type `any`.

Next we can add back in the args:

> `(...args: any[]) => any`

`...args: any[]` is using the Rest Parameters construct which essentially says that there can be any number of parameters of the provided type `any`. Because there are an unknown amount of `any` parameters, the type of the argument is an array of `any`.

So hopefully now it makes sense that this is a function that accepts any amount of arguments (of type `any`) and returns type `any`.

Finally we can add back the `new` keyword to get:

> `new (...args: any[]) => any`

The `new` keyword here specifies that this function can be treated as a class constructor function and called with the `new` keyword.

This gives us the whole picture that the function is *a function that accepts any amount of arguments (of type `any`) that returns type `any` and can be used as a constructor function with the `new` keyword*.

When taken in the context of the API, it is essentially allowing you to pass any class constructor to the function.

Answer (score 8):

Breaking it down into pieces:

**`new`**
This keyword in TypeScript specifies what the constructor should look like, for the given property. Nice explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623422/1678614.

**`(...args: any[]) => any`**
This syntax describe a function type (the constructor is a function).

**`...`**
is the ES6 spread operator. It's shorthand for listing out all array elements one by one.

**`any[]`**
means that `args` is an array and it's elements can be of any type.

**`=> any`**
specifies the return type of the function. In this case it allows the constructor to return any type.

Answer (score 3):

```
new (...args: any[]) => any
```

This type specifies a function that accepts any number of arguments that are `any` type, returns `any` value, and can be invoked with `new`.

A constructor is a special type of function that enforces invocation with the `new` keyword at runtime, but in TypeScript, that can be statically detected, so `targetTypeConstructor` is specifying an arbitrary constructor as the  second parameter to `isInstance()`.

To that end, it seems redundant to check

```
typeof targetTypeConstructor === "function"
```

as that's already enforced by `targetTypeConstructor : new (...args: any[]) => any` at compile-time by TypeScript.

If the passed value is `null`, it is already invalidated by the `targetTypeConstructor && ...` conditional, which *is* necessary at runtime to prevent `object instanceof targetTypeConstructor` from throwing `TypeError` in the event that `targetTypeConstructor` is actually `null` due to Step 4 
in [§12.10.4 of the ECMAScript Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-instanceofoperator):

> **12.10.4 Runtime Semantics: InstanceofOperator ( *V*, *target* )**
>
> 1. If Type(*target*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 2. Let *instOfHandler* be ? GetMethod(*target*, @@hasInstance).
> 3. If *instOfHandler* is not **undefined**, then
>
>    a. Return ToBoolean(? Call(*instOfHandler*, *target*, « *V* »)).
> 4. If IsCallable(*target*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 5. Return ? OrdinaryHasInstance(*target*, *V*).
>
> > NOTE
> >
> > Steps 4 and 5 provide compatibility with previous editions of ECMAScript that did not use a @@hasInstance method to define the **instanceof** operator semantics. If an object does not define or inherit @@hasInstance it uses the default **instanceof** semantics.

Comment: OK So effectively new (...args: ...) is typescripts way of saying that the function is a constructor function type?

Comment: Specifically, the `new (...) => ...` is what indicates a constructor.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the typeof targetTypeConstructor === function is redundant because the last check object instanceOf targetTypeConstructor will be false if the always if hte targetTypeConstructor is not a function ... wonder if it's safer to just keep it in the event that the java runtime for some reason throws an exception in the future ... or in the past for certain runtimes ....?

Comment: No, it's redundant because TypeScript already enforces that type at compile-time, so the parameter will never be anything but `null` or `typeof === 'function'`. The check should just be `targetTypeConstructor && object instanceof targetTypeConstructor`, the first conditional being necessary to prevent the second one from throwing `TypeError`

Comment: Don't we also have to consider the corresponding javascript runtime version, `function (object, targetTypeConstructor)`, and the runtime cases where perhaps targetTypeConstructor is something other than a function (User error scenarios)?

Comment: User error will result in a TypeScript compilation error -- it would never reach runtime.

Comment: What happens if we publish the library to NPM, compile for both ES6 and Typescript use cases, and someone uses it for an ES6 library without typescript support?

Comment: Then they'd have a hell of a time going through the process of setting up a babel environment just to circumvent the use of TypeScript in the library and be able to use decorator functions like this, which have no native support. Simple solution. Don't release ES6 pre-compiled output, and specify that the point of these typings is to avoid the overhead of runtime checks in the first place.

Comment: I agree with you on the recommendation, but try to always make libraries compatible with other runtimes anyways, because I know there are a ton of people (React ...) that will just use straight up ES without any typescript.  I love typescript though, and I'm trying my best to stick with it!

Answer (score 1):

Means that the parameter `targetTypeConstructor` is a function that accepts parameters and **can be used as a constructor (you can use with `new` keyword and create instances)**. You can pass a simple function or a class that are not *abstracts*.

For more you can check an example in the [**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aclass%20Check%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20isInstance(targetTypeConstructor%3A%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20targetTypeConstructor%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20typeof%20targetTypeConstructor%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ACheck.isInstance(B)%0D%0ACheck.isInstance(A))