# "new() =>" in typescript constructor

Tags: typescript

I just found a [code snipped](https://dev.to/devtronic/german-clean-architecture-in-einem-typescript-projekt-1-2-3lna) in TypeScript what I do not really understand.

```
export abstract class Presenter<TView> {
  public viewModel: TView;

  constructor(private template: new() => TView,
  ) {
  }

  public reset(): void {
    const model = new this.template();

    if (this.viewModel == null) {
      this.viewModel = model;
    } else {
      Object.assign(this.viewModel, model);
    }
  }
}
```

I am especially talking about the *template: new() => TView* here.
I can see that it is a generic class and if a type parameter "string" was used, the code in the constructor would resolve to:

```
new() => string
```

here.

But I cannot help myself understanding the sense of that. Its not a function declaration - I never saw "new" in such a context.
Also I do not know what:

```
const model = new this.template();
```

means than. 
Can anybody explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is new() in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622778/what-is-new-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

This means that `template` is a constructor with no parameters, that returns a `TView` when invoked with `new`. It is described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) in the typescript handbook.