# TypeScript New() in Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, factory

Please, I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/905494) and  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623422/905494).

However, consider the following use case:

```
//Connection Type
interface Connection {
}

// Model class
class  BaseModel {
    created_at?: Date;
    updated_at?: Date;

    constructor(public connection?: Connection) {}
}

// Class that implements BaseModel
class  UserModel extends BaseModel {

    constructor() {super()}
}

// A factory function which takes type T that must extend BaseModel
 function Model<T extends BaseModel>(name: string) {
  return (target: { new (): T }) => {
       console.log(target.prototype);
  };                                          
}
//type of target in the anonymous function returned by Model function factory
interface OurTarget {
    new(): UserModel;
}

// this does not give error
var ourFunctionModel = Model("user");
// this does not give error
var userModel = new  UserModel();
// TS2345 not assignable error
ourFunctionModel(userModel);

//Correct Usage provided in comments by [@keith][3]
const ourFunctionModel = Model("user")(UserModel);
```

In the anonymous function of Model which takes a target which of type OurTarget. OurTarget defines a new() which for UserModel which extends BaseModel. Why is the last line of code throwing error, it was given the right type?

Here is the code on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGED2YxSREbVAb2AF9hgkAbBAZztVQCF6oBZTAEympOCZMkMKAmhcA+mID8ALlQARMVADcAwQFcADl2WSZ8pdDXqh2OhBgb8mGAAotGgEbUQSVEmy58hMHIxeeATYAJQkFBRUtAxMAKp0sJw8fFAAHtBgXIysCUm8-IIe5pbWELZ2YcR02rAVEZQCcBpgPkR51AA8ACqoaRlZLGztAHx2YAgAtlDyFjDgAOaV6iIQGjBgqHYQCDDzUBDyxKi4AO6bIfI9ZGEAvMMFqGQqhS+vb+8fguSU4NDwyGgAPJrLo7PYQB5MU4VeTxRLcXhqSKeMAWVCYNYAMWarTA7VQN1Q7TsACINAkYCSQmoUWjyfDkgTjlAzqg4TBidTgBiYNiWsE8QjqHZ6RyhVzgEA)

Comment: Well `userModel` is an object, and `ourFunctionModel` is expecting a constructor.   `ourFunctionModel(UserModel)` would work here.

Comment: You are completely right because what was needed in the factory was a prototype of target. Please move comment to answer let me accept. See edit.