# TypeScript create object from generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to create an object based on a generic type, but can't figure out the syntax.  What I'm wanting is something like this contrived example:

```js
myfunc<T>() : T[] {
    let obj = new T();
    let obj2 = new T();

    return [obj, obj2];
}
```

The `new T()` of course doesn't compile.  In C# I'd add a `where T : new` constraint to make that work.  What's the equivalent in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new object from type parameter in generic class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/how-to-create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remember that TypeScript types (including generics) only exist at compile time. Also, in JavaScript the constructor function is of a different type that the object it constructs.

You probably are looking for something like this (assuming your constructor takes zero parameters):

```
function foo<T>(C: { new(): T }): T[] {
    return [new C(), new C()];
}

class SomeClass {}

// here you need to pass the constructor function
const array = foo(SomeClass);
```

There, `C` is the constructor function you will use at runtime and `T` is a type that will be inferred as the resulting of the construction.