# How create instance of generic type parameter in type script

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

I have a generic function like this :

```
export function f<T >(json: Object): T {
return new T()
```

}

but I got this error when com`'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

how should i handle this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/how-to-create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class-in-typescript

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```js
export function f<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```