# Make a generic type Array<keyof T> require all keys of T

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I would like to declare a type that requires all the keys of a given type `T` to be included in an array, e.g.:

```
checkKeys<T>(arr: Array<keyof T>): void {
  // do something
}

interface MyType {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Currently if a call `checkKeys<MyType>`, TS will consider the value passed as valid if it contains any key of `MyType` (`id | value`):

```
checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'value']); // valid

checkKeys<MyType>(['id']); // valid

checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'values']); // invalid
```

Is it possible to require that all keys are specified in the array?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an [Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) if the value has to be of a specific *type*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips an Enum is what I had in mind as well, but I still needed the interface `MyType`, so I wanted to avoid having duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with an array type (at  least I am not aware of a way to spread the union of keys into a tuple type, there may be one I'm just not aware of it). An alternative would be to use an object literal to achieve a similar effect. The syntax is a bit more verbose but the compiler will validate that only the correct keys are specified. We will use the `Record` mapped type and we can use the `0` literal types for values as only the keys matter.

```
function checkKeys<T>(o: Record<keyof T, 0>): void {
     // do something
}

interface MyType {
    id: string;
    value: number;
}

checkKeys<MyType>({ id: 0, value: 0 }); // valid

checkKeys<MyType>({ id: 0 }); // invalid

checkKeys<MyType>({ id: 0, values: 0 }); // invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround but actually the solution is not perfect:

```
interface MyType {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
const myType: MyType = {
   id: '',
   value: 0
};
type ArrType<T> = Array<keyof T>;
function isMyTypeArr<T>(arg: any[]): arg is ArrType<T> {
  return arg.length === Object.keys(myType).length;
}

function checkKeys<T>(arr: ArrType<T>): void {
  if (isMyTypeArr(arr)) {
    console.log(arr.length);
    // some other stuff
  }
}
checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'x']); // TS error
checkKeys<MyType>(['id']); // no console because of Type Guard
checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'value']); // SUCCESS: console logs '2'
```

The idea is to create a simple object which implements the initial interface. We need this object in order to get its keys length for comparison in the `isMyTypeArr` Type Guard. Type Guard simply compare the length of arrays - if they have the same length, it means that you provide all properties.

---

**Edit**

Added another similar (more generic) solution - the main differences are:

- use class with constructor params which implements the initial interface;
- this class has `length` property (because basically it's a constructor function) we can use it in our Type Guard;
- we also have to pass class name as a second parameter in order to get it constructor args length. We cannot use generic type `T` for this, because the compiled JS has all the type information erased, we can't use `T` for our purpose, [check this post for more deta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/how-to-create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class-in-typescript)

So this is the final solution:

```
interface IMyType {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
class MyType implements IMyType {
  constructor(public id: string = '', public value: number = 0) {}
}
type ArrType<T> = Array<keyof T>;
function isMyTypeArr<T>(arg: ArrType<T>, TClass: new () => T): arg is ArrType<T> {
  return arg.length === TClass.length;
}

function checkKeys<T>(arr: ArrType<T>, TClass: new () => T): void {
  if (isMyTypeArr<T>(arr, TClass)) {
    console.log(arr.length);
    // some other stuff
  }
}

checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'x'], MyType); // TS error
checkKeys<MyType>(['id'], MyType); // no console because of Type Guard
checkKeys<MyType>(['id', 'value'], MyType); // SUCCESS: console logs '2'
```

> Notice that these examples are based on [TypeScript issue 13267](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13267)

p.s. also created a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sherlock-tp8h4m?file=index.ts) of both examples

Comment: I would use `Record<keyof MyType, 0>`for the `myType` constant. If the interface has nested objects creating compatible values for each field may be difficult and the value is irrelevant to usage. Also your solution has the drawback of beeing a runtime check not a compile time one.

Comment: @sherlock thank's for the very complete suggestion. it is indeed close to what I am doing right now, that's why I was looking for a solution for compile time :-)