# How do I create type for Array of enum values with mandatory members in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How do I create `type` / `interface` (`AnyColorsWithBlackAndWhite` in example below) for an array of enum values with mandatory members? I need `black` AND `white` to be always present. I tried to intersect, omit and extend both `Array<Color>` and `Array<Color.black | Color.white>` at the same time but no luck so far:

```js
enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  yellow,
  blue,
  black,
  white,
}

interface AnyColorsWithBlackAndWhite
  extends Array<Color | Color.black | Color.white> {}

export const Correct: AnyColorsWithBlackAndWhite = [Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.black, Color.white];

export const Wrong1: AnyColorsWithBlackAndWhite = [Color.red, Color.yellow];

export const Wrong2: AnyColorsWithBlackAndWhite = [Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.black];
```

Comment: At least *closetly* related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028791/make-a-generic-type-arraykeyof-t-require-all-keys-of-t?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C56.9813 Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462472/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-array-of-singlekey-with-all-different-keys

Comment: Alternative approach [here](https://tsplay.dev/WPzbKN)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine's solution with the OP's "correct" and "wrong" examples: https://tsplay.dev/w8BbVm

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways, you either create function for inference and validation or you create a union of all allowed states.
First approach:

```js
enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  yellow,
  blue,
  black,
  white,
}

type RequiredElements = Color.black | Color.white

const withRequired = <
  Item extends Color,
  List extends Item[]
>(list: RequiredElements[] extends [...List] ? List : never) => list

const ok = withRequired([Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.black, Color.white]) // ok
const error = withRequired([Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.black]) // error
```

[enter link description here](https://tsplay.dev/NlLJXN)

Second:

```js
enum Color {
  red,
  green,
  yellow,
  blue,
  black,
  white,
}

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string | number, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never
  ? S extends Color.black | Color.white
  ? [...R, S] : [...R, S?] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>,
    S extends Color.black | Color.white ? [...R, S]
    : [...R, S?]
  >;
}[U];

type Ok = TupleUnion<Color>

export const Correct: Ok = [Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.black, Color.white]; // ok
export const COrrect1: Ok = [Color.red, Color.white, Color.yellow, Color.black]; // ok

export const Wrong1: Ok = [Color.red, Color.yellow]; // error

export const Wrong2: Ok = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.black]; // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NV7L5m)

As you might have noticed, I have created all possible states of this array. It is a lot: 6! = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

`TupleUnion` generates a combination of all allowed states and makes every  non black and white color as optional

Comment: @T.J.Crowder unfortunately, unions are not ok :(( just tested it

Comment: Ah, yeah, because you can only have one rest element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unions still rules :D