# Typescript type parameter with gernic argument list

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to use a type parameter as an generic like in C++?

```js
interface Genic1ParamWrapperConstructor<T>{
    new<T2>():T<T2>;
}
```

The interesting part is **T<T2>** because the typescript compiler generates an error saying: Type 'T' is not a generic

Comment: [maybe this will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class)

Comment: `T<T2>` is not possible

Answer (score 0):

To use this with an interface, like in your case, you would need something along the lines of

```
interface GenericIdentityFn<T> {
    (arg: T): T;
}

function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn<number> = identity;
```

Mind that you should use either  on the interface to set the type for the whole interface, or for each method individually. That is probably where the mistake is.
So:

```
interface Genic1ParamWrapperConstructor<T>{
    new(arg: T): T;
}
```

Or

```
interface Genic1ParamWrapperConstructor{
    new<T>(arg: T): T;
}
```

depending on your preferenes.

you can also use the any param

```
    function identity(arg: any): any {
        return arg;
    }
let output = identity("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)