# Typescript: Typed interface doesn't allow a value from its type string litteral

Tags: typescript, generics

I've created a scale down version of my problem.

The class must initialize the default value of its "status" property. It's of type T which extends the string litteral type "PossibleStatus" made of 3 possible strings.

Typescript doesn't accept this. Can you help me figure out why?

[A stackblitz to see it live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-generics-litteral-type)

```
export type PossibleStatuses = 'idle' | 'on' | 'off';

export class StatefulNode<T extends PossibleStatuses> {

  private status: T = 'idle';

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class

Comment: hi @HanyHabib, thanks, but it seems related to the "T extends " using a string litteral. I've updated my question to better reflect this issue.

Comment: hello Jem to work , i think you need to do it as  private status: PossibleStatuses = 'idle'; because the compiled JavaScript has all the type information erased, you can't use T to new up an object.

Comment: Thanks @HanyHabib; it seems my use of the "extends" keyword is wrong. I expect it to mean "at least the 3 strings specified above" and that seems to be my problem. I'm now looking for the right way to code that.

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates why you cannot initiate the status (`type X = 'on'` extends `PossibleStatuses` but doesn't include `'idle'`):

```
export type PossibleStatuses = 'idle' | 'on' | 'off';

export class StatefulNode<T extends PossibleStatuses> {
  // Error
  private status: T = 'idle';
}

// Because
const unsafe = new StatefulNode<'on'>();
```

Comment: Thanks; I understeand now that "extends" doesn't mean "at least these 3 strings". Is there a way to say so? Because I have a "SpecializedStatefulNode" that has 5 possible statuses, including the 3 base statuses.

Comment: Ok, I understand - "extends" in the case of a string litteral type means "these, or a subset of these". The wider type would otherwise be "string". Is this understanding correct?