# In Typescript's generic class, how to return typeof T

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a generic class and I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  getModel(): typeof T { return T; }
}
```

How can I return T and define the return type?

for the return type, I have seen someone using `new (...args) => T`

But I can't `return T` in typescript, it says:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I fix it?

**Update 1:** A different use case

I modified the above generic class to an abstract class:

```
class Data {}

abstract class MyClass<T extends Data> {
  abstract getModel(): typeof T;
}
```

It gives error:
`'T' only referes to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

But `T extends Data`. I can define a return type as `typeof Data`, but why can't I define a return type as `typeof T`?

Comment: you can't return a raw `type` or `interface` definition in Typescript

Comment: Types *do not exist at runtime*. They are erased, gone, non-existent. Trying to return a *type* makes no logical sense from the code's perspective, since you *cannot use that* value. It's not there.

Comment: @m_callens where do you get that info from? I can do something like this:
`class B {}`
Then
`class A {
  getB(): typeof B { return B; }
}`

Comment: @Comtaler that's a `class`, it's a concrete thing that isn't removed. The *type systems*, however, only exists *at compile time*. It's the fundamental way that TypeScript works - it checks the code for type safety, then produces *JavaScript code*. So, you run *JavaScript code* afterwards. [Check the FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-check-at-run-time-if-an-object-implements-some-interface)

Comment: @VLAZ for a compiled language, it may not make sense, but I am coming from javascript. and in javascript, there is usage for it. With the above example I posted, you can do `const typeB = new A().getB(); const a = new typeB();`

Comment: @Comtaler again, that's NOT PART OF THE TYPE SYSTEM! You are talking about a concrete thing that will exist at runtime. Please make a distinction.

Comment: @VLAZ say if I want to do what I describe, I want to return a constructor of the generic type so that I can use it to construct the generic type object. Is there a way to do it in typescript?

Comment: @Comtaler did you check https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2037 ..

Comment: @Comtaler no. Yet again, the generic type *does not exist* at runtime. A function `function f<T>(): T {}` is turned into just `function f() {}`. There is no `T` at all when you execute it - how would you know what `T` is if it's *gone*? You need to use something concrete which *exists* at runtime. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class). You may need to pass a constructor or an instance or something to determine what constructor to call. But, again, the type system isn't there at runtime.

Comment: @HanyHabib Thanks for the info. That helps.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the info too. I think there is currently no solution in typescript for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Now I understand why I can't use T in runtime and I have updated my question to remove the usage of T in runtime code.

Answer (score 1):

Since `T` is already a type there is no reason to use `typeof` with it, simply remove it and the code will compile.

Comment: it compiles, but it doesn't do what I intended to do. The function does not return an instance of T, it returns the class signature of T.