# default value of Function as constructor parameter

Tags: typescript

following the solutions of this problem: [Create a new object from type parameter in generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class)

I have this simple code:

```
class TestBase {
    hi() {
        alert('Hi from base');
    }
}

class TestSub extends TestBase {
    hi() {
        alert('Hi from sub');
    }
}

class TestTwo<T extends TestBase = TestBase> {
    constructor(private testType: new () => T) { // Set TestBase constructor as default value for testType ?
    }

    getNew() : T {
        return new this.testType();
    }
}

//var test = new TestTwo<TestBase>(TestBase);
var test = new TestTwo<TestSub>(TestSub);

var example = test.getNew();
example.hi();

// With a default value for testType, I will be able to write something like:
var test2 = new TestTwo();
test2.getNew().hi(); // Should print "Hi from base"
```

How is it possible to set a default value for testType constructor within testTwo constructor ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because this is valid code:

```typescript
class TestSub3 extends TestBase { prop3: number = 42; }
class TestSub4 extends TestBase { prop4: string = "answer"; }
// ...
const test3 = new TestTwo<TestSub3>(); // Note no argument = uses default
const test4 = new TestTwo<TestSub4>(); // Note no argument = also uses default
```

There's no default constructor you can provide that satisfies that code, because for `test3` it would have to provide something creating a `TestSub3` and for `test4` it would have to provide something creating a `TestSub4`.

You might consider having a function that returns a class instead, probably an overloaded one so that it can return something creating `TestBase` classes if you provide no argument for it, but some type that extends `TestBase` when you do.